# How to know if windows update is currently running

Tags: c#, c++, windows-update

I am developing a C# .net3.5 application.

The application manages the power and among other things it also set the machine to sleep if there is no active process.

I found out that is Windows Update is currently running while I set the computer to sleep the machine will go to sleep and will not wait for Windows Update to finish the execution.

How can I know of Windows Update is currently running? I saw somewhere (don't remember where) that if windows update is running then "Wuauclt" or "trustedInstaller" are running.
The problem is that TrustedInstaller is running also when Windows Update is not running.

I need to find a way to determine whether Windows Update is currently running.

Comment: Why would you do this in code when Windows already offers "sleep on idle" functionality?

Comment: Because "sleep on Idle" will put the machine to sleep even if Windows Update is running. i.e. Windows Update doesn't stop the OS from going to sleep.

Comment: That I didn't know. Thanks for sharing.